# UDP VideoChat Program

Tags: videochat

Hey I'm thinking of making a UDP videochat program, and I was wondering whether it should transmit keyframes and interframes or just whole frames? I'm thinking of just having the webcam take pictures at small time intervals and sending them as UDP packets to the other client but that seems like it would take too much bandwidth. Is there a way to cut down the size and resolution of a pictures dramatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a compressed image format like GIF or JPG and resizing the images from the web came to say 320x240 would significantly reduce size and resolution. Also, UDP packets need to meet certain size requirements to be routed over the internet (as apposed to a LAN).